# Python selecting variables based inside function

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to create function that can pull information from an API library and I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass a variable selection into the function without being read as a value.

code example:

```
def get_list(api, val = None):
    response =[]
    list = api
    for i in list:
        response.append(f'i.{val}')
    return (response)


devices = get_list(api.devices.all(), 'name')

print(devices )
```

Give me a long list of "i.name"

I need to resolve **i.name** as a variable selection and not as an actual value

I have tired:

```
response.append(vars()[f'i.{val}']) # locals(), globals()
```

But I I get the error:    "KeyError: 'i.name'"

I think the problem is the 'i.name' doesn't really exist as a variable within the function.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure I understand what you are wanting. You are trying to pass in an the name of an attribute in your `val` function argument and get the value of that attribute in your for loop?

Comment: I can't understand the question/problem, can you try explaining it differently with more code and some examples? Even with this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/74290027/13564014 I cant understand how they are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand is that you want to write a function so you will not have to repeat the `for`

```py
ip_list = []
for device in lnms.devices.all():
    ip_list.append(device.ip)

name_list = []
for device in lnms.devices.all():
    ip_list.append(device.sysName)
```

First of all on your code, you are using `list` as a variable which you should not cause `list` is a built-in keyword.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74289645/13564014) explains why your code doesn't work

This is how it would work

```py
def get_data(devices, attr):
    response = []
    for device in devices:
        response.append(getattr(device, attr))
    return response
```

Or even shorter using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```py
def get_data(devices, attr):
    return [getattr(device, attr) for device in devices]
```

and then you can do

```py
ip_list = []
ip_list = get_data(lnms.devices.all(), 'ip')

name_list = []
name_list = get_data(lnms.devices.all(), 'sysName')
```

And if you don want to repeat `lnms.devices.all()`
You can write the functions like

```py
def get_data_from_devices(attr):
    response = []
    for device in lnms.devices.all():
        response.append(getattr(device, attr))
    return response
```

Or with list comprehension

```py
def get_data_from_devices(attr):
    return [getattr(device, attr) for device in lnms.devices.all()]
```

And then you would call them as

```py
ip_list = []
ip_list = get_data_from_devices('ip')

name_list = []
name_list = get_data_from_devices('sysName')
```

PS: Needs better names for functions

Comment: with "response.append(device[key])" 

I get: TypeError: 'LibreNMSEndpoint' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Skylark I assumed `device` is a dictionary but its an `LibreNMSEndpoint object` so I have updated the code to how it should work now. Can you try it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you call this function with devices, you are passing the argument 'name' as your "val" which you then loop over and append to results.

It would be helpful if you could also include what your desired result here would be since that is not clear at the moment.

Comment: When you loop over `list` inside the function (which is not a good choice for a variable name since it shadows pythons built in list function) you are currently not using `i` as the variable you declare in the for loop, but just as a string value. If you want to use the actual value of your declared `i` and the API value is a string, you can write `response.append(f'{i}.{val}')`. If it s not a string then `response.append(f'{str(i)}.{val}')`

Comment: response.append(f'{i}.{val}')
    =     TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: response.append(f'{str(i)}.{val}') = TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a LibrenmsAPI library to read data from LibreNMS

regular GET request would look like:

```py
ip_list []
for device in lnms.devices.all():
    ip_list.append(device.ip)

name_list []
for device in lnms.devices.all():
    ip_list.append(device.sysName)
```

So in order not have to make every variation of an api request I need, the idea would be to have a "list" function.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new at Python and I can see from the text above I have not explained myself very well, so here is my attempt to make things clearer.

command "lnms_device_names = get_data(lnms.devices.all(), 'sysName')"

### Original attempts:

```py
def get_data(devices, key):
    response = []
    for device in devices:
        response.append(device.key)
    return response

# => Endpoint devices/29/key does not exists

def get_data(devices, key):
    response = []
    for device in devices:
        response.append(f'device.{key}')
    return response

# => ['device.sysName', 'device.sysName', 'device.sysName', 'device.sysName']
```

### Failed attempts using advice in this thread:

```py
def get_data(devices, key):
    return [device[key] for device in devices]

# => TypeError: 'LibreNMSEndpoint' object is not subscriptable

def get_data(devices, key):
    response = []
    for device in devices:
        response.append(device[key])
    return response

# => TypeError: 'LibreNMSEndpoint' object is not subscriptable

def get_data(devices, key):
    response = []
    for device in devices:
        response.append(f'{device}.{key}') # same result with f'{str(device)}.{key}'
    return response

# => full data dump no filtering by key
```

## how it looks when no function is used

```py
#WORKS:
lnms_device_names = []
for device in lnms.devices.all():
    lnms_device_names.append(device.sysName)

# => ['dc2-h1-ipn03', 'dc2-h1-spine1', 'dc2-h1-spine2', 'dc2-h1-leaf1']
```

#### Data structure:

```
{
            "device_id": 1,
            "inserted": "2022-08-15 15:50:33",
            "hostname": "172.21.142.10",
            "sysName": "dc2-h1-ipn03",
            "display": null,
            "ip": "",
            "overwrite_ip": null,
            "community": "xxxxxxx",
            "authlevel": null,
            "authname": null,
            "authpass": null,
            "authalgo": null,
            "cryptopass": null,
            "cryptoalgo": null,
            "snmpver": "v2c",
            "port": 161,
            "transport": "udp",
            "timeout": null,
            "retries": null,
            "snmp_disable": 0,
            "bgpLocalAs": 1,
            "sysObjectID": ".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.12.3.1.3.1812",
            "sysDescr": "Cisco NX-OS(tm) nxos.7.0.3.I7.9.bin, Software (nxos), Version 7.0(3)I7(9), RELEASE SOFTWARE Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Cisco Systems, Inc. Compiled 8/27/2020 4:00:00",
            "sysContact": null,
            "version": "7.0(3)I7(9)",
            "hardware": "N9K-C93180YC-EX",
            "features": null,
            "location_id": 1,
            "os": "nxos",
            "status": 1,
            "status_reason": "",
            "ignore": 0,
            "disabled": 0,
            "uptime": 47671869,
            "agent_uptime": 0,
            "last_polled": "2022-11-02 15:28:35",
            "last_poll_attempted": null,
            "last_polled_timetaken": 8.46,
            "last_discovered_timetaken": 293.18,
            "last_discovered": "2022-11-02 12:05:18",
            "last_ping": "2022-11-02 15:31:02",
            "last_ping_timetaken": 1.83,
            "purpose": null,
            "type": "network",
            "serial": "xxxxxx",
            "icon": "cisco.svg",
            "poller_group": 0,
            "override_sysLocation": 0,
            "notes": null,
            "port_association_mode": 1,
            "max_depth": 0,
            "disable_notify": 0,
            "dependency_parent_id": null,
            "dependency_parent_hostname": null,
            "location": "xxxxx",
            "lat": 64.132453,
            "lng": -21.877419
        },
        {
            "device_id": 2,
            ....
            ....
```